# Emulator: FB: openColorBuffer cb handle 0x58 not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Error :Emulator: FB: openColorBuffer cb handle 0x58 not found

after running my -program on android studio i am  getting this error in the log cat
 of course message on emulator coming says your app keeping stopping .

my program is using google map

code all are good as i got no messages or warner regarding it i think the problem is regarding the emulator any idea pleas
any idea

Comment: Your emulator os version ?

Answer (score 1):

I've the same error testing new Android-P, with build tools version "28.0.0-rc1" and support app compat "28.0.0-alpha1".

I solve the problem doing the following:

1. On Android Studio:

   - Download the Android-P SDK version.
   - Getting for AVD the Emulator with Android-P and Google Play Store.
2. On Gradle (Android/Dependencies):

   - Use compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
   - Use buildToolsVersion "28.0.0-rc1"
   - Use targetSdkVersion 27
   - Use implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
   - Use implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
   - Use implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'

Please tell me if it's enough for you.